# Creating booking overview (table) from MySQL Database - Combining arrays

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, multidimensional-array

I am desperate because of my lack of programming experience.
I am working on a small WordPress plugin, a room booking system.

Now my problem is to create the daily overview.
In the database, there is a table with all bookings looking like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|id|user_id|     starttime     |     endtime       |room|type|
---+-------+-------------------+-------------------+----+-----
|1 |    101|2017-08-24 11:00:00|2017-08-24 12:30:00|12  | 4  |
|2 | ...
```

The overview / calendar / schedule for every day should be made as an HTML-Table using Bootstrap and look like the following:

```
Time    Conference Room     Meeting Room     Lobby
07:00       Mr. T   
08:00       Mr. T
09:00                          C.J.P.         Mrs. L.
10:00
11:00
12:00       Mrs. M
```

So the free timeslots should be empty columns.

To achieve this, I started using a function to create all starttimes:

```
$times_array = array();
    $timing_interval = get_option('timing');
   for ($hours = get_option('starttime'); $hours < get_option('endtime'); $hours++) {
      for ($m = 0; $m < 60; $m += $timing_interval) {
      $starttime_html = sprintf('%02u:%02u', $hours, $m);
      $times_array[$starttime_html]='';
    }
}
```

Afterwards I created an array containing the already saved bookings:

```
$booking_array = array();
    $statement = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT {$mpbs_prefix}_bookings.id, user_id, wp_users.user_nicename AS username_nice, starttime, facility_id, roomname, equipment_1, {$mpbs_prefix}_equipment.name AS eq_1_name, equipment_2 FROM {$mpbs_prefix}_bookings, {$mpbs_prefix}_facilities, {$mpbs_prefix}_equipment, wp_users WHERE user_id = wp_users.ID AND equipment_1 = {$mpbs_prefix}_equipment.id AND {$mpbs_prefix}_facilities.id = {$mpbs_prefix}_bookings.facility_id AND starttime >= '2017-08-22 00:00:00'"),ARRAY_A);

    $bookingrow = 0;


foreach($statement as $actualbookings) {

   $starttime_currentday = explode(" ",$statement[$bookingrow]['starttime']);

   $starttime_curr_hm = substr($starttime_currentday[1],0,5);

     $booking_array[$bookingrow] =
       array('starttime_of_booking'=>$starttime_curr_hm, 'facliId'=>$statement[$bookingrow]['facility_id'],'userid'=> $statement[$bookingrow]['username_nice'], 'horse_1_name' => $statement[$bookingrow]['horse_1_name']);
             $bookingrow++;
 }
```

As there are a lot of rooms (facilities) in different categories, I chose a tabbed navigation from Bootstrap.

Therefore I created a function to "draw" the table using information from three directions:

- The column heads directly from the database
- the starting times created in PHP (see above)
- the already booked times and facilities saved in my `$booking_array`

As the HTML-table is created row wise, I thought it would be a good approach to check if the starttime is also available in the `$booking_array` and if yes to add a cell containing the username.
So far that worked, but now I wanted to have all free slots as empty cells. So I tried a lot but always end up in a table with hundreds of empty rows.

In my last approach I used a function I found here, to check if the starttime is not in my multidimensional associative array (`$booking_array`) and to add the empty cell:

```
$drawTable = function($funcFormCat, $funcFacId) use ($mpbs_overview_category_query, $times_array, $booking_array) {

echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
echo "<thead>";
//echo "<th class='text-center'></th>";

foreach ($mpbs_overview_category_query as $overview_formcategories) {
    if ($overview_formcategories->formcategory == $funcFormCat && $overview_formcategories->facility_id == $funcFacId) {
        echo "<th class='text-center' id='$overview_formcategories->facility_id'>" . $overview_formcategories->facility ."</th>";
    }
}
echo "</thead>";

foreach ($times_array as $timeskey => $timesvalue) {
    echo "<tr>";
    // echo "<td class='text-center'>.</td>";
    for ($booking_array_id = 0; $booking_array_id < count($booking_array); $booking_array_id++ ) {
        if ($booking_array[$booking_array_id]['starttime_of_booking'] == $timeskey && $booking_array[$booking_array_id]['facliId'] == $funcFacId ) {
            echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $booking_array[$booking_array_id]['username'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        elseif (in_array_r($timeskey, $booking_array)==false) {     
            echo "<td class='text-center'>**</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }

        }

}
```

My arrays do contain the following format:

`$times_array`

```
Array ( [07:00] => [07:30] => [08:00] => [08:30] => [09:00] => [09:30] => [10:00] => [10:30] => [11:00] => [11:30] => [12:00] => [12:30] => [13:00] => [13:30] => [14:00] => [14:30] => [15:00] => [15:30] => [16:00] => [16:30] => [17:00] => [17:30] => [18:00] => [18:30] => [19:00] => [19:30] => [20:00] => [20:30] => [21:00] => [21:30] => )
```

`$booking_array`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [starttime_of_booking] => 08:00 [facliId] => 6 [userid] => Mr T [equipment] => Beamer ) [1] => Array ( [starttime_of_booking] => 14:00 [facliId] => 4 [userid] => Mrs. L [equipment] => Flipchart ) [2] => Array ( [starttime_of_booking] => 14:00 [facliId] => 9 [userid] => Mrs. M [equipment] => TV-Set ) [3] => Array ( [starttime_of_booking] => 13:00 [facliId] => 8 [userid] => C.J.P. [equipment] => Stuff )
```

As I am trying around for hours now and do not get a correct overview, I would be very happy for any hints, tips or suggestions!

Thanks in advance.
Regards 
Lars

---

To clarify, what I want to achieve, I add some more information here:

What I want is to create a HTML-Table, which is populated from the 3 sources:

At first he table's heading should be made by a SQL-query to get the room names and their ids. (`<thead><th id='facility_id'>room1</th><th id='facility_id'>room2</th id='facility_id'>...</thead>`

Afterwards in the 1st data row in the 1st column the 1st starttime coming from `$times_array` should be printed. (`"<td>".$timeskey."</td>"`).

All remaining cells should also be formatted as HTML-Cells.

Now comes the tricky part (for me), as I want to populate those cells, where already a booking was made.

For example the conference room is booked from 07:00 to 09:00 by Mr.T.

To achieve this without Ajax, I created the array `$booking_array` with the data from my bookings database table.

Now I am stuck on writing a function, which draws my HTML-Table with all necessary information at the right place.

A `<tr>` tag is printed to open a new row. In the next step a cell with the starttime is added. And now I want to iterate through my `$bookings_array` for any booking starting at this time and printing the username to the corresponding column.

As I did not get that to work, in one table, I tried to achieve it by creating a single table for each room containing the starttimes and the column with the booking data / free slots. But the table gets hundreds of rows.

Comment: It looks to me like you're doing (almost) everything in a sensible way - and I think you must be very close, but I'm a lousy PHP coder, so I'll leave it for others to answer - except to say that you should always qualify all column names; it makes the query much easier for us (and, in due course, you) to understand

Comment: You have provided lots of information, but it's unclear what exactly you are asking. What exactly would you like us to help with... is it just something to do with the last 2 arrays you included?

Comment: What I want is to create a HTML-Table, which is populated from the 3 sources:
The table's heading should be made by a SQL-query to get the room names and their ids. (`<thead><th>room1</th><th>room2</th>...</thead>`).
Afterwards in the 1st data row in the 1st column the 1st starttime from `$times_array` should be printed. (`"<td>".$timeskey."</td>"`)
If there is a booking in `$booking_array` for any of the rooms beginning at this starttime, the booker's username should be written in the exact same row in the corresponding col of the room. 
Finally all other columns should be just empty cols.

Comment: OK, and how do the last 2 arrays fit in? Also, you should update your question when you're adding more information or clarifying what you need, not everyone will read all the comments.

Comment: I see your list lists every full hour, but bookings can be made on half past as well. How do you want to deal with that ?

Comment: You are right, but that will be controlled by the variable `$timing_interval`. 
At the end the interval will be 15 minute steps.
Right now there is only some test data, but I think this issue does not change anything for this problem, as bookings, which do not start equal to the `times_array` should be ignored.